# Debug Console menu Item missing within Kudu on Azure App Services?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to edit my files using Kudu on my app service. All the tutorials I find have a menu item called "Debug console" and they navigate to the CMD and have access to a file manager.

My App Service Kudu looks like this -> [Menu with no option of debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mupB.png)
I was expecting it to have a debug console menu item that allowed me to access the file manager from within kudu.

This is what the tutorials show -> [Menu with debug console with dropdown of cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buZhS.png) I want to add/edit lines of code into files from my wwwroot area but I do not know how to do that without access to the kudu file manager.

Edit: I have two app service environments, one being ran on the standard tier and another being ran on premium and neither have this menu item in Kudu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue of being unable to access the file manager from within Kudu by adding '/newui' to the url path. So, the final path that worked to find the information that I needed was just, 'nameofwebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui'

Comment: Wooow Love this hidden trick!
Thanks so much @WPAZ as it works great on an App Service under the Free Tier/.Net 6 Linux Env Appplication ;)
This allow to browse files from the browser and even drag and drop content as it shown in all tutorials.
On the other side just to do that I prefer to connect to the Web App vía FTP with FileZilla and you can find the config details for that in the same App Service but this newui comes with log viewer, a Bash console plus process explorer. Quite Impressive!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on the free tier it would explain why some options are not available.

Try upgrading to Basic Tier.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention it but my app service is currently being ran on the standard tier plan.

Comment: Are you running in a Linux container where SSH is not enabled?

Comment: Hi, I am using a Linux container but SSH is enabled.  In the SSH tab, it shows that the connection is established.

Answer (score 0):

You don't see the **Debug console** menu because you're running App Service on Linux. That console is available only if you're using on Windows.

That being said, click on the **SSH** link and you'll be able to use the **nano** editor to make your changes.

EDIT********************************

You mentioned in a comment that you deployed the **WordPress on App Service** from the marketplace. I created an instance and I was able to launch the **Advanced Tools**, click on the **Bash menu** to open a terminal and I was able to see the files by typing **cd site/wwwroot**.

I confirm that the nano editor is not installed and that you can't sudo. However, **vim** is installed. So **option 1** is to use vim to edit the file and **option 2** is to install a file manager plugin in Wordpress so you can edit the file. I you never used vim before, make sure that you know the basic commands like save and quit before launching it.

Comment: I clicked on the SSH link, but it just shows a terminal. How do I get into the nano editor?

Comment: You type nano at the command prompt

Comment: It looks like sudo and nano are not currently installed since attempting to use nano in the terminal returns with an error saying it isn't found. Tried to install with the sudo command but that isn't currently installed either. Ill go ahead and install those to use the nano editor. Thanks.

Comment: Are you deploying an app or a container? This info should be part of your question.

Comment: It says the publishing model is a container? I opened up the instance using the Wordpress on App Service in the marketplace. Sorry, I am new to Azure, and am having a hard time knowing what specific information is relevant.

Comment: No problem, we're here to help. We just need the right info. I'll spin an instance later to do further investigations.